# read excel file from build.gradle

Tags: gradle

i am new to gradle.Can someone please help me out to find out a way in which we can read some values from an excel file in build.gradle script. these values will be used to decide the testng test suites thatneed to be run dynamically

Comment: i have tried to  refer to the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53918618/read-excel-file-from-build-gradle  but it didnt work.                                                          buildscript {
dependencies {
 classpath files  ("libs/poi/poi-4.0.1.jar")
}
} then call it in task                                                                                               test.doFirst{
File file = new File("<ExcelPath>/MasterTestData.xlsx");
  FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
def Workbook= new  org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

Answer (score 0):

use imports to add poi jars and use them as you do in normal java program 
remmber to import packges at the first very first section(top) of build.gradle file

buildscript {

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    //  classpath group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.0'

classpath group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.13'
classpath group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.13'

}